# Website field won't show on page layout

Tags: fields, field-level-security

I added the standard Website field to the page layout, but it won't show up.

[image]

[image]

Googled this quite a bit and found this [SO question about standard fields not showing up](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9744/why-arent-standard-fields-visible-on-page-layout) but it is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field doesn't have permission for the profile(s) you're trying to view it as. Go to Setup > Customize > Leads > Fields > Website > Set Field-Level Security, and apply the Visible attribute to profiles that should be able to view the field.